# How to add the standard sharepoint list item context menu?

Tags: javascript, 2013

we have written a webpart that outputs titles of list items. We now want to add to each of those items the standard flyout menu (see the picture) below, but don't know how so far.

Can you help us out here?

[image]

Comment: Why do you use this approach? the simplest way is to create custom view of this list that contains only title field and then add the OOTB list view web part to the page.

Comment: Also you can use client rendering template to change view look of your list.

Comment: That sure would work but there will be many more requirements to this webpart so we started with this custom approach.

Comment: I'm not sure how it works in SP2013, in SP2010 I used RenderAsHtml function of SPField. The filed name was 'LinkTitle'.

Comment: Did you use the SPView.JSLink and SPField.JSLink ?